# Android : screen width Dialog with adMob

Tags: java, android, dialog, admob

I want to create dialog with adMob , but it always gives an error , that its not enough place to put it . so is it possible to make dialog width equal to screen width ?

here is how i create it all :

```
public void CreateDialog(){
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Loading...");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(d.getContext());
    ll.setLayoutParams( new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.addView(adView);
    d.setContentView(ll);
    d.show();
}
```

// AdView is loading normally , and working without dialog;

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to show an ad in a dialog box? Isn't that for alerts and to prompt the user?

Comment: em... I just need to show it in the dialog , alertDialog  or something like that .

Comment: this is a late reply for sure any how
but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779629/admob-ad-on-custom-dialog help you.