# Custom ads on admob android studio based on keyword

Tags: android, ads, adsense, google-ads-api

I have searched online but had not luck so far in my research, I have set up admobs in my android app and now I only want relevant ads to show up based on keyword that I set. My app is based on toys, so I only want ads related to toys to show

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Looking at this: [Admob ad on custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779629/admob-ad-on-custom-dialog)

This person has used:

```
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
        keywords.add("game");
        request.setKeywords(keywords);
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work in this code? When you look at the logcat, do you see "game"?

Comment: It provides no error, but when I use this code and set a keyword, for example to toys it does not show ads only related to toys but instead the ads are normal (random) like it was before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() 
.addKeyword("game").build();
.adView.loadAd(request);
```

You can try with this, but here are some examples, maybe you find what you allso need:

**1.Test ads**

Set up test ads by passing your hashed Device ID to AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice:

```
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
.build();
```

**2.Location**

Location targeting information may also be specified in the AdRequest:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.setLocation(location)
.build();
```

**3.Gender**

If your app already knows a user's gender, it can provide that information in the ad request for targeting purposes. The information is also forwarded to ad network mediation adapters if mediation is enabled.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.setGender(AdRequest.GENDER_FEMALE)
.build();
```

**4.Birthday**

If your app already knows a user's birthday, it can provide that information in the ad request for targeting purposes. This information is also forwarded to ad network mediation adapters if mediation is enabled.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.setBirthday(new GregorianCalendar(1985, 1, 1).getTime())
.build();
```

**5.Designed for Families setting**

If you have opted your app in to Google Play's Designed for Families program and you show ads in your app, you need to ensure those ads comply with the Designed for Families program requirements and ad policies.

Ad requests can be tagged as designed for families by setting the is_designed_for_families parameter to true in the extras:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
    .build();
```

**6.Child-directed setting**

For purposes of the Children's Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA), there is a setting called "tag for child directed treatment".

As an app developer, you can indicate whether you want Google to treat your content as child-directed when you make an ad request. If you indicate that you want Google to treat your content as child-directed, we will take steps to disable IBA and remarketing ads on that ad request. The setting can be used with all versions of the Google Play services SDK, via `AdRequest.Builder.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(boolean)`:

If you set `tagForChildDirectedTreatment` to `true`, you will indicate that your content should be treated as child-directed for purposes of COPPA.
If you set `tagForChildDirectedTreatment` to `false`, you will indicate that your content should not be treated as child-directed for purposes of COPPA.
If you do not set `tagForChildDirectedTreatment`, ad requests will include no indication of how you would like your content treated with respect to COPPA.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) .build();
```

By setting this tag, you certify that this notification is accurate and you are authorized to act on behalf of the owner of the app. You understand that abuse of this setting may result in termination of your Google account.

**7.Keyword**

Add a keyword for targeting purposes.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .addKeyword(someKeyword) .build();
```

**Loading an ad with targeting**

Once your request targeting information is set, call loadAd on the AdView with your AdRequest instance.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.setLocation(location)
.setGender(AdRequest.GENDER_FEMALE)
.setBirthday(new GregorianCalendar(1985, 1, 1).getTime())
.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
.addKeyword("game")
.build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Additional information can be found on [this link.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting)

Comment: This is excellent information. Would you by any chance know how to apply these extra parameters when mediating via MoPub? (Without changing the adapter - want to do it generically for all mediated ad networks). Specially (designed for family and child tragetting)

Comment: Can multi-word keywords be used @Stanojkovic? For example would addKeyword("strategy games") be effective?  I can't find any info about the use of long-tail keywords in relation to AdMob's addKeyword method...

Comment: @Zippy, yes, you can use multiple keywords but i don't know if "strategy games" keyword would be effective. You need to test that.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, it does not look like keywords are supported.

There have been [various questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/keyword/google-admob-ads-sdk/0q6IG9NoYGk/OKPjWbySbBYJ) over the [years](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/setkeywords/google-admob-ads-sdk/JkBeYpxIpRg) that all have the [same answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/about$20keywords/google-admob-ads-sdk/lyh8UXlNH5M/ryQeUrFsoUoJ):

The [documentation for targeting ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting) does not include any information on using keywords.

You can add keywords to your `AdRequest` using `addKeyword(String keyword)` in `AdRequest.Builder`, which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#addKeyword(java.lang.String)). An example call would be like below:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addKeyword("game").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

However, as stated above- it does not look like these keywords are being used on the backend.

The AdMob support site shows that there are three ways [advertisers can choose to target their ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3521319?hl=en-GB)- context (keywords, presumably implicit rather than explicit), placement, and interest.

You can filter outside of your app by [allowing and blocking ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150235?hl=en-GB), which if you truly do only want to show ads related to toys, then you will have to block everything except the toys category shown in the [general category list](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3151007?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=3052991).

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this :

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addKeyword("game");
```

Now you can build the adrequest.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am quite new, do I need to add something else to this code or is this complete?

Comment: Trying this: 'AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder().addKeyword("game");
        builder.setRequestAgent("game");' doesn;t give any error however, it doesn't show ads based on games, its random ads

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply . You need to create new request :
AdRequest request = builder.build();
I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation to add a keyword for targeting purposes.
You can use this single line code.
public AdRequest.Builder addKeyword (String keyword)